# Error in launching Java Web Start Applications

Tags: java, eclipse, web, jar, java-web-start

I followed all steps in  [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/) to create an JWS app but after downloading the .jnlp file, I couldn't run the .jnlp file.

Here is the error announcement(open this image in a new tab to see it more clearly) [image] By the way, from where should I jar all classes? In this example, I wrote the command line: jar -cf TestJnlp.jar*.* from within E:\Java\CuongNguyen\project04.

Comment: Don't post images of text, ***copy and paste the text itself** so it can be searched, or used with a screen reader.

Comment: I'd prefer to see an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28163833/edit) rather than 'thanks'.  Here, thanks is about as useful as tits on a bull.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to sign your jar file with jarsigner. That is, you didn't do step 6 in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've just figured it out. The problem is how to create jar file properly. 
    I found out that if i follow the above tutorial's command: jar -cf TestJnlp.jar *.* from inside "Project04", there will be no "Main-Class attribute" in "MANIFEST.FM" file, thus, causing my problem. Then I decided to create jar file the way mentioned in book Head First Java (I created a manifest.txt file with the content "Main-Class: com.mkyong.TestJnlp" and then created the jar file with the command: "jar -cvmf manifest.txt TestJnlp.jar com" from within bin folder.